# Can a plotted graph be included with a Tooltip?

Tags: plotting, tooltip

I have a set of spectral training data for 2 thousand plus colors.  Right now each color can be compared with a result a ListLinePlot made to show both on a graph with RMSE.  I would like to be able to plot the data differently as a 3DBarGraph and use the ListLinePlot result as a tooltip when mousing over each bar of the graph.  The Bar graph part is no problem at all, but the tooltip portion appears to be out of the realms of possibility.

Can Mathematica use a plotted graph as a tooltip (or some other function) to do the same?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question, but isn't it something like this:


BarChart3D @ 
 Table[Tooltip[i^2, 
   ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, i, .1}]]], {i, 1, 5}]

Comment: It appears you have understood it quite well! Thanks! This solution will work just fine!

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @Pavel, looks like you can post that as an answer. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comment above posting this as an answer.

To get the desired behaviour you can wrap the elements of your chart in the symbolic wrapper (Tooltip in this case). Here's a crude approximation:

```
BarChart3D @ Table[
  Tooltip[i^2,
     ListLinePlot[Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, i, .1}]
    ]
  ]
 , {i, 1, 5}
]
```

Tooltip can contain anything in it's second argument and Mathematica will try to display the expression as usual but in the tooltip popup.